# Inserting New row into table inside MYSQL & using union all to combine 2 different query

Tags: mysql, union-all

I was trying to insert a new set of row into my current table 'ccat' calling it 'Other' whereby I have set the condition that the count of each category inside if added is lesser than 30, will be summed up into 1 new row called 'Other' under the campaign column. However, after I had managed to add this new row with the values 'Other' and '125' (the sum of all the category that is lesser than 30), I could manage to query my result using UNION ALL but **I could not order by the 'num_campaigns' in a descending order**. Here are my set of codes:

```
INSERT INTO ccat (campaign, category)
 VALUES (
    'Other',
    ( 
        SELECT SUM(num_campaigns)FROM
            (
                SELECT category, count(category) as num_campaigns
                FROM ccat
                GROUP BY category
                HAVING count(*) <30
            ) AS Other
    )
    );
```

[image]

```
SELECT category, count(*) as num_campaigns
    FROM ccat
    GROUP BY category
    HAVING count(*) >=30
UNION 
SELECT campaign as category, category as num_campaigns
    FROM ccat
    WHERE campaign ='other'
    GROUP BY category
ORDER BY num_campaigns DESC
```

What I am currently seeing right now:

[image: ![enter image description here]

What I am hoping to achieve:

[image]

Set of data:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ccat`;
CREATE TABLE `ccat` (
  `campaign` text,
  `category` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `ccat` (`campaign`, `category`) VALUES
('Hope Beyond Borders 2020', 'Fundraising'),
('Hope Beyond Borders 2020', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Family of 10 needs help to make ends meet', 'Children'),
('Family of 10 needs help to make ends meet', 'Living Expenses'),
('Family of 10 needs help to make ends meet', 'Family'),
('Raya for Hope 2020', 'Raya For Hope'),
('Covid-19 Migrant Support Coalition', 'COVID-19'),
('Covid-19 Migrant Support Coalition', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Emergency Fund for Ray of Hope beneficiaries', 'Fundraising'),
('Give hope to Vivian in her painful battle against end stage cervical cancer', 'Medical'),
('Help Home Bakers through this Circuit Breaker', 'Fundraising'),
('Help Home Bakers through this Circuit Breaker', 'Living Expenses'),
('Help Home Bakers through this Circuit Breaker', 'Food'),
('Family of 5 loses income due to Covid-19', 'Children'),
('Family of 5 loses income due to Covid-19', 'Family'),
('Give Hope for Mdm Noordewi and her family', 'Living Expenses'),
('Give Hope for Mdm Noordewi and her family', 'Family'),
('Project Providence', 'Fundraising'),
('Project Providence', 'Living Expenses'),
('Project Providence', 'Migrant Workers'),
('beINVOLVED - Migrant Workers Relief Efforts', 'Fundraising'),
('beINVOLVED - Migrant Workers Relief Efforts', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Good Food For Community', 'Children'),
('Good Food For Community', 'COVID-19'),
('Good Food For Community', 'Fundraising'),
('Good Food For Community', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Good Food For Community', 'Elderly'),
('Good Food For Community', 'Family'),
('Good Food For Community', 'Food'),
('Feeding the Hearts and Tummies of Underprivileged Kids', 'Children'),
('Feeding the Hearts and Tummies of Underprivileged Kids', 'COVID-19'),
('Feeding the Hearts and Tummies of Underprivileged Kids', 'Fundraising'),
('Feeding the Hearts and Tummies of Underprivileged Kids', 'Family'),
('Single Parents Giving Circle', 'Giving Circle'),
('Single Parents Giving Circle', 'Single Parents'),
('Your support can help lighten the financial burdens of Aidah as she fights cancer to get well again!', 'Children'),
('Your support can help lighten the financial burdens of Aidah as she fights cancer to get well again!', 'Family'),
('Caring Amidst COVID-19 Fund', 'COVID-19'),
('Caring Amidst COVID-19 Fund', 'Fundraising'),
('Caring Amidst COVID-19 Fund', 'Living Expenses'),
('Caring Amidst COVID-19 Fund', 'Family'),
('Caring Amidst COVID-19 Fund', 'Medical'),
('ItsRainingRaincoats', 'COVID-19'),
('ItsRainingRaincoats', 'Fundraising'),
('ItsRainingRaincoats', 'Migrant Workers'),
('DO GOOD . SEND LOVE', 'COVID-19'),
('DO GOOD . SEND LOVE', 'Fundraising'),
('DO GOOD . SEND LOVE', 'Family'),
('DO GOOD . SEND LOVE', 'Food'),
('DO GOOD . SEND LOVE', 'Special Needs'),
('Bandwidth - Apart yet Together', 'COVID-19'),
('Bandwidth - Apart yet Together', 'Fundraising'),
('Help a cancer patient as her husband looks for a job', 'Living Expenses'),
('Help a cancer patient as her husband looks for a job', 'Family'),
('Single Mum of 3 needs your help, her youngest child has Stage 4 of a rare cancer', 'Children'),
('Single Mum of 3 needs your help, her youngest child has Stage 4 of a rare cancer', 'COVID-19'),
('Single Mum of 3 needs your help, her youngest child has Stage 4 of a rare cancer', 'Living Expenses'),
('Single Mum of 3 needs your help, her youngest child has Stage 4 of a rare cancer', 'Family'),
('Single Mum of 3 needs your help, her youngest child has Stage 4 of a rare cancer', 'Single Parents'),
('Adopt-a-Bento', 'COVID-19'),
('Adopt-a-Bento', 'Fundraising'),
('Adopt-a-Bento', 'Food'),
('Give Mr Kumar a second chance', 'Living Expenses'),
('Help Rajen better himself and get back in touch with his family', 'Living Expenses'),
('Mr Silvaraj wants to turn over a new leaf', 'Transport'),
('Mr Silvaraj wants to turn over a new leaf', 'Living Expenses'),
('Mr Silvaraj wants to turn over a new leaf', 'Medical'),
('Help Sam continue onto his dream', 'Living Expenses'),
('Help Mr Raja and his elderly parents', 'Living Expenses'),
('Help Mr Raja and his elderly parents', 'Family'),
('Mr Raj wants to help his family', 'Living Expenses'),
('Mr Raj wants to help his family', 'Family'),
('Help 6,000 Socially Isolated & At-Risk Elderly Overcome COVID-19', 'COVID-19'),
('Help 6,000 Socially Isolated & At-Risk Elderly Overcome COVID-19', 'Fundraising'),
('Help 6,000 Socially Isolated & At-Risk Elderly Overcome COVID-19', 'Elderly'),
('FDW suddenly finds a lump in her thyroid, sent home for surgery', 'Foreign Domestic Worker'),
('FDW suddenly finds a lump in her thyroid, sent home for surgery', 'Fundraising'),
('FDW suddenly finds a lump in her thyroid, sent home for surgery', 'Medical'),
('Spread warmth & health through a cup of Chai', 'COVID-19'),
('Spread warmth & health through a cup of Chai', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Spread Love to Lee Ah Mooi Old Age Home', 'COVID-19'),
('Spread Love to Lee Ah Mooi Old Age Home', 'Fundraising'),
('Spread Love to Lee Ah Mooi Old Age Home', 'Elderly'),
('Give hope to Mr M and his family back home', 'Living Expenses'),
('Give hope to Mr M and his family back home', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Help Mr WQ support his wife and her medical costs back home', 'Living Expenses'),
('Help Mr WQ support his wife and her medical costs back home', 'Migrant Workers'),
('He came to Singapore with high hopes of escaping poverty and providing for his family', 'Living Expenses'),
('He came to Singapore with high hopes of escaping poverty and providing for his family', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Can You Help Our Local Elderly During This COVID-19 Situation?', 'COVID-19'),
('Can You Help Our Local Elderly During This COVID-19 Situation?', 'Fundraising'),
('Can You Help Our Local Elderly During This COVID-19 Situation?', 'Elderly'),
('Give hope to a single mum with 4 children who lost her job recently', 'Children'),
('Give hope to a single mum with 4 children who lost her job recently', 'COVID-19'),
('Give hope to a single mum with 4 children who lost her job recently', 'Family'),
('Give hope to a single mum with 4 children who lost her job recently', 'Single Parents'),
('Mum of 4 struggling with illnesses holds on for her children', 'Children'),
('Mum of 4 struggling with illnesses holds on for her children', 'COVID-19'),
('Mum of 4 struggling with illnesses holds on for her children', 'Living Expenses'),
('Mum of 4 struggling with illnesses holds on for her children', 'Family'),
('Mum of 4 struggling with illnesses holds on for her children', 'Food'),
('41 year old single mum who lost her job wants to pick herself up for her family', 'Children'),
('41 year old single mum who lost her job wants to pick herself up for her family', 'COVID-19'),
('41 year old single mum who lost her job wants to pick herself up for her family', 'Elderly'),
('41 year old single mum who lost her job wants to pick herself up for her family', 'Family'),
('41 year old single mum who lost her job wants to pick herself up for her family', 'Food'),
('41 year old single mum who lost her job wants to pick herself up for her family', 'Single Parents'),
('Give hope to a caregiver, Ashura and help lighten her load', 'Children'),
('Give hope to a caregiver, Ashura and help lighten her load', 'COVID-19'),
('Give hope to a caregiver, Ashura and help lighten her load', 'Elderly'),
('Give hope to a caregiver, Ashura and help lighten her load', 'Family'),
('Give hope to a caregiver, Ashura and help lighten her load', 'Single Parents'),
('Give hope to a caregiver, Ashura and help lighten her load', 'Special Needs'),
('Give Hope and Support to Hashik who recently lost his mum to illness', 'Elderly'),
('Give Hope and Support to Hashik who recently lost his mum to illness', 'Single Parents'),
('Buy a Meal for Needy Elderly @ $3 per meal', 'Fundraising'),
('Buy a Meal for Needy Elderly @ $3 per meal', 'Elderly'),
('Buy a Meal for Needy Elderly @ $3 per meal', 'Food'),
('Abused single mum with two autistic sons needs your help to start afresh', 'Children'),
('Abused single mum with two autistic sons needs your help to start afresh', 'COVID-19'),
('Abused single mum with two autistic sons needs your help to start afresh', 'Transport'),
('Abused single mum with two autistic sons needs your help to start afresh', 'Single Parents'),
('Abused single mum with two autistic sons needs your help to start afresh', 'Special Needs'),
('Give hope to an injured sole breadwinner as he awaits his assessment', 'Living Expenses'),
('Give hope to an injured sole breadwinner as he awaits his assessment', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Give hope to an injured sole breadwinner as he awaits his assessment', 'Accident'),
('Donate to a 29 year old suffering from mental health issues to help her get back on her feet', 'Living Expenses'),
('Donate to a 29 year old suffering from mental health issues to help her get back on her feet', 'Medical'),
('Help support Mr JH while he gets legal help to validate his claim of work injury', 'Living Expenses'),
('Help support Mr JH while he gets legal help to validate his claim of work injury', 'Migrant Workers'),
('Help support Mr JH while he
```

[image: Sample of source file after importing]

Comment: can you provide the data before the result ideally as fiddle? see  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @tadman, thank you for the advice! I will try my best to adapt to this :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using another method and it will get me the result that I want to achieve. Codes are provided below:

```
CREATE TABLE result
AS (SELECT category, count(*) as num_campaigns
    FROM ccat
    GROUP BY category
    HAVING count(*) >=30);

INSERT INTO result (category, num_campaigns)
VALUES (
    'Other',
    ( 
        SELECT SUM(num_campaigns)FROM
            (
                SELECT category, count(category) as num_campaigns
                FROM ccat
                GROUP BY category
                HAVING count(*) <30 
            ) AS Other
    )
    );

SELECT category, num_campaigns
FROM result
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY num_campaigns DESC
```

Comment: Unless this is an answer, just edit the question to include more details like this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).